# large alloc error when extracting 3D Image patches in python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to extract small 3D patches (example patch size 20x20x4) from a 3D Image of size 250x250x250 with stride 1 for every axis. I'll be extracting all possible patches as I'll be running a function on each patch and returning the result in the form of a 3D image with the result of the current patch assigned to the center voxel of the patch. For extracting the patches I'll be using the code below :

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib import stride_tricks

def cutup(data, blck, strd):
    sh = np.array(data.shape)
    blck = np.asanyarray(blck)
    strd = np.asanyarray(strd)
    nbl = (sh - blck) // strd + 1
    strides = np.r_[data.strides * strd, data.strides]
    dims = np.r_[nbl, blck]
    data6 = stride_tricks.as_strided(data, strides=strides, shape=dims)
    return data6.reshape(-1, *blck)

#demo
x = np.zeros((250,250,250), int)
y = cutup(x, (20, 20, 4), (1, 1, 1))
```

I'm running this on google colab which has around 12gigs of ram. Since the result is large number of patches, I'm getting a large alloc error and then the kernel restarts. I think splitting the image in to parts would work, but If I do so how should I write the code in order for it to consider the neighbouring voxels? Is there a smart way to do this?

Comment: "With stride 1 for every axis": is either impossible, or you are using a non-standard definition of "stride".

Comment: neither `as_strided` nor `reshape` allocate new data. If you get a memory error, it happens elsewhere. That means you have not provided nearly enough information about the actual problem.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 78.6 GiB for an array with shape (231, 231, 247, 20, 20, 4) and data type int32` - on the `return data6.reshape(-1, *blck)` line,

Comment: Change `return data6.reshape(-1, *blck)` to `return data6`. Then you can iterate over the *patches* - BUT they each have a shape of `(231, 247, 20, 20, 4)` ? did you adapt `cutup` from something you found here on SO?  I've seen solutions for windowed operations like this (advancing window by one pixel in each dimension) that use either numpy or scipy convolution/

Comment: What is the point of reshaping after `as_strided`? I'm not sure why you get the error there, since it should never reallocate, but it's still fishy.

Comment: @MadPhysicist stride of 1 is possible. I didnt get your statement.

Comment: After extracting patches, I'll be reshaping them into column vectors with each patch reshaped into a 1D matrix.

Comment: @wwii, yes, I did find the implementation here. I wasn't able to find a different implementation. The one on scipy is for a 2d one i guess.

Comment: @wwii, If I only used data6, the output is of shape (231, 231, 247, 20, 20, 4). What I dont understand is when I try to reshape it to (231,231,247,-1). I get large alloc error. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: `Is there a reason for this?` - I do not know. The docs state `This will be a new view object if possible; **otherwise**, it will be a copy.` - maybe it is making a copy not a view. Why do you need to reshape it at all? Why do you need to reshape it before returning from the function? Can't you operate on the (20,20,4) patches?

Comment: `as_strided` creates a `view`, which doesn't use any additional memory.  But, `reshape` creates a copy, effectively expanding all those virtual, strided dimensions, to the full size.  While `reshape` tries to return a `view` there are cases like this where it can't  (reshape after a transpose is another case).  `reshape` doesn't just change the `shape`, it also changes `strides` (which will break the carefully constructed `as_strided` ones).

Comment: A stride of 1 is possible, but unlikely in every axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reshape the *newly strided* array/view before returning.

```
def cutup(data, blck, strd):
    sh = np.array(data.shape)
    blck = np.asanyarray(blck)
    strd = np.asanyarray(strd)
    nbl = (sh - blck) // strd + 1
    strides = np.r_[data.strides * strd, data.strides]
    dims = np.r_[nbl, blck]
    data6 = stride_tricks.as_strided(data, strides=strides, shape=dims)
    return data6
```

Then iteratate over the patches.

```
p = np.zeros((250,250,250), int)
q = cutup(p, (20, 20, 4), (1, 1, 1))
print(f'windowed shape : {q.shape}')
print()
for i,x in enumerate(q):
    print(f'x.shape:{x.shape}')
    for j,y in enumerate(x):
        print(f'\ty.shape:{y.shape}')
        for k,z in enumerate(y):
            print(f'\t\tz.shape:{z.shape}')
            if k==5: break
        break
    break
>>>
windowed shape : (231, 231, 247, 20, 20, 4)

x.shape:(231, 247, 20, 20, 4)
        y.shape:(247, 20, 20, 4)
                z.shape:(20, 20, 4)
                z.shape:(20, 20, 4)
                z.shape:(20, 20, 4)
                z.shape:(20, 20, 4)
                z.shape:(20, 20, 4)
                z.shape:(20, 20, 4)
```

Your example will *produce* an array (or a view of the array) with a shape of `(231,231, 247, 20, 20, 4)` or thirteen million+ 3-d patches.

That will solve your memory allocation problem.

---

> when I try to reshape it to (231,231,247,-1). I get large alloc error

If your operation requires the last three dimensions to be flattened, do that in your iteration.

```
for i,x in enumerate(q):
    for j,y in enumerate(x):
        for k,z in enumerate(y):
            z = z.reshape(-1)
            print(f'\t\tz.shape:{z.shape}')
            if k==5: break
        break
    break
```

Looks like you can do that reshape in the outermost loop - at least for a zeros array.

```
for i,x in enumerate(q):
    zero,one,*last = x.shape
    x = x.reshape(zero,one,-1)
    print(f'x.shape:{x.shape}')
    for j,y in enumerate(x):
        print(f'\ty.shape:{y.shape}')
        for k,z in enumerate(y):
            print(f'\t\tz.shape:{z.shape}')
            break
        break
    break
>>>
x.shape:(231, 247, 1600)
        y.shape:(247, 1600)
                z.shape:(1600,)
```

---

> Is there a smart way to do this?

If you can figure out how to vectorize your operation so that you only need to iterate over the first dimension or the first and second dimensions you can speed up your processing.  That should be a separate question if you encounter problems.

Comment: This is perfect.I'll try this out. Thanks a ton